# My question has to do with linear depictions!

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear depiction is given $ T_{M2*2}(R)->R^2 $
$ T(A)=(a11+a22,a12+a21) $
Where A is a matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
                                 a_{11} & a_{12} \\
                                 a_{21} & a_{22} \\
                               \end{bmatrix}

$1$) Prove that $T$ is a linear depiction

$2$) Find the kernel of depiction $T$

$3$) Check if kerf $T$ is the total of antisymmetric tables $ 2*2 $

I managed to solve the first one but I have trouble solving number $2$) and $3$)!

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Could you reformat this? The  mathjax/LaTeX looks incomplete right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel of such transformation includes all matrices $M_{2\times 2}$ such that $T(M)=0$. This requires all matrices with $a_{11}+a_{22}=0$ and $a_{12}+a_{21}=0$ and leads to $a_{11}=-a_{22}$ and $a_{12}=-a_{21}$. So the dimension of the kernel is $2$. $$\ker(T)=\lbrace all \ 2\times 2 \ matrices \ with \ a_{11}=-a_{22}  \ and \ a_{12}=-a_{21} \rbrace$$also the set of antisymmetric matrices is a special case of this one with $a_{11}=a_{22}=0$ and $a_{12}=-a_{21}$. So this subspace includes all of those kinds of matrices.